# buffer video before playing it on iphone

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, stream, udp

I'm doing some testing which during I would like to:
- Take a video that is in the app folder
- load that video to memory (buffer it)
- play the bufferd frames from the memory
All made on iPhone

Actually,
I would like to play a video from memory.
(I also want to load the video to memory by frames).

I hope it clear enough.

How can I accomplish this?

Tnx

**EDIT:**
Maybe I can point my question a little more..
I have a server that streams video via UDP (let's say that for the simuloation I'm using VLC to stream via UDP).
What do I have to do and implement in order to get the UDP stream from VLC and display it on the screen of my I device (of course i'm talking about writing code and not using VLC streamer :-) ).

Hope that's better and that I'll get some answers now.

Tnx

Answer (score 0):

A video has to be buffered only if you receive the video from a server over internet via packets/Streams.

Else you can just play the video using below code:-

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"yourVideo" ofType:@"yourVideoType" inDirectory:@""]];

MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
[[player view] setFrame:[self.view bounds]]; 
[self.view addSubview:[player view]];
[player play];
[player release];
```

You can implement the notification `MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification`, if you are playing the videos after fetching over some data service.(GPRS,2G, Internet.)

Comment: As part of the tests I want to see how it works before working on the streaming.. I actually want to simulate a streaming while using a local video..